# Returning the value of deep properties if they exist

Tags: javascript, function, object, return

I wrote this function to search for and return the value of deep properties in an object and would like to know if there is a way to use recursion or something similar to make the function do the same thing but with less code (and possibly to remove the limit of at most five properties deep that can be tested).

The function will return a deep property value if it exists, otherwise returns undefined.

```
function getDeep(o, p2, p3, p4, p5) {
    if (p5 !== undefined) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p2) && o[p2].hasOwnProperty(p3) && o[p2][p3].hasOwnProperty(p4) && o[p2][p3][p4].hasOwnProperty(p5)) {
            return o[p2][p3][p4][p5];
        }
    } else if (p4 !== undefined) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p2) && o[p2].hasOwnProperty(p3) && o[p2][p3].hasOwnProperty(p4)) {
            return o[p2][p3][p4];
        }
    } else if (p3 !== undefined) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p2) && o[p2].hasOwnProperty(p3)) {
            return o[p2][p3];
        }
    } else if (p2 !== undefined) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p2)) {
            return o[p2];
        }
    } else if (o !== undefined) {
        return o;
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var obj = {a:{b:{c:1}}};
    window.console.log(getDeep(obj, 'a', 'b', 'c')); // returns 1;
    window.console.log(getDeep(obj, 'a', 'b', 'd')); // returns undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.reduce` is useful for this.

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/NU4vF/2

```
function getDeep() {
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(obj, prop) {
        return obj && obj[prop];
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just caught that. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Very nice.  Seems to work on all situations I've tested so far.  Excellent work, plus it's forcing me to learn some new concepts.

Answer (score 0):

With underscore/[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#get), you can get a deep property with

```
_.get(obj, 'a.b.c'); //returns 1
_.get(obj, 'a.b.d'); //returns undefined
```

and specify the default return value with the third argument:

```
_.get(obj, 'a.b.c', null); //returns 1
_.get(obj, 'a.b.d', null); //returns null
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will allow full or partial application and will account for array access. It also is compatible with older browsers which do not support ES5 features.

**Demo**: https://tonicdev.com/wilmoore/576587d46ea8b6140097eb1e

```
function get(path) {
  function _get(source) {
    var end = path.length;
    var idx = -1;
    var ref = source;

    while (++idx < end) {
      if (!ref) break;
      ref = ref[path[idx]];
    }

    return ref;
  }

  return (arguments.length > 1)
    ? _get(arguments[1])
    : _get.bind(null)
}
```